# mac/linux terminal - How do you find the total memory usage of a process, and all its children recursively?

Tags: memory, terminal

I would like to find how much memory a process and its children are using. Knowning a single process's usage is not useful sometimes, e.g. when you have `tmux` running and you want to see how much memory all the bash processes plus all `vim`s running and whatnot as well - summed up.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question for linux but IDK how to do that on a mac.

[How can I display the memory usage of each process if I do a 'ps -ef'?](https://superuser.com/questions/102005/how-can-i-display-the-memory-usage-of-each-process-if-i-do-a-ps-ef)

Here is the script they used to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for pid in $(ps -ef | awk '{print $2}'); do
    if [ -f /proc/$pid/smaps ]; then
        echo "* Mem usage for PID $pid"     
        rss=$(awk 'BEGIN {i=0} /^Rss/ {i = i + $2} END {print i}' /proc/$pid/smaps)
        pss=$(awk 'BEGIN {i=0} /^Pss/ {i = i + $2 + 0.5} END {print i}' /proc/$pid/smaps)
        sc=$(awk 'BEGIN {i=0} /^Shared_Clean/ {i = i + $2} END {print i}' /proc/$pid/smaps)            
        sd=$(awk 'BEGIN {i=0} /^Shared_Dirty/ {i = i + $2} END {print i}' /proc/$pid/smaps)
        pc=$(awk 'BEGIN {i=0} /^Private_Clean/ {i = i + $2} END {print i}' /proc/$pid/smaps)
        pd=$(awk 'BEGIN {i=0} /^Private_Dirty/ {i = i + $2} END {print i}' /proc/$pid/smaps)
        echo "-- Rss: $rss kB" 
        echo "-- Pss: $pss kB"
        echo "Shared Clean $sc kB"
        echo "Shared Dirty $sd kB"
        echo "Private $(($pd + $pc)) kB"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Mac doesn't have `/proc` so this is definitely the wrong answer to copy. The other question does have other solutions which are portable, by quick glance; and many of them also do not have this massive antipattern of running a huge number of teeny tiny Awk scripts instead of a single well-defined one.

Comment: If you find questions which are already answered at another question, answering them is usually the wrong thing to do. Just leave a comment that this is a possible duplicate instead. (Once you have more rep, you can participate in properly nominating something as a duplicate question.)